# Why isn't the __new__() method of my class returning an instance of the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class

I am trying to figure out a way to create predimensioned lists to avoid the limitations of list objects such as not being able to insert far past the end of the list. So this code builds the list the way I want it to, but I didn't notice till I started to implement the `__str__()` method that this to string method was never actually being called.

And it seems it is this class is creating `list` not the `ArrayList` that it is called and defined. Where did my `ArrayList` class go? So, in order to call the `__str__()` from the class, I have to brute-force it which really defeats the purpose, and I also wanted to add other methods in the mix that won't call directly either, I am sure.

So, I am wondering if there is something I can do to fix this or maybe a better approach. I am not looking to use another existing class either such as for arrays. At this point, this is pedagogical and am looking to continue in this same direction. Here is the code I have:

```py
import copy

class ArrayList(list):
    def __init__(self, *dim, initial = []):
        pass

    def __new__(cls, *dim, initial=[]):
        template = None
        for d in range(len(dim)-1, -1, -1):
            if template is None:
                template = [initial for _ in range(dim[d])]
            else:
                template = [copy.deepcopy(template) for _ in range(dim[d])]
        return template

    def __str__(self):
        print('using override')
        print(len(self))
        for i in range(len(self)):
            print(self[i])
        return

var1 = ArrayList(4,3,2,initial=0)
print(var1)
print(type(var1))   # <class 'list'>
print(var1 is ArrayList)    #False
print(ArrayList.__str__(var1))

# var2 = ArrayList(3,2,2,initial='a')
# var2[1][0][1] = 5
# print(var2)
# print("~"*20)
# var1[2][2] = 17
# print(*var1, sep='\n')
# print(len(var1))
# print("~"*20)
# print(ArrayList.__str__(var1))  #this works
```

Comment: "the object returned should be the type of the class" - as in *you should make it be that type*, usually by calling `super.__new__(yourclass, ...)`. It's not going to take whatever you return and change its type somehow. (also you're technically allowed to return whatever type you want from `__new__`, not that you should be doing that here).

Comment: Why are you using the `__new__()` method instead of `__init__()`? Note that whatever `__new__()` returns is what gets assigned to `var1` in your case.

Comment: Also this looks more like a job for `__init__` than `__new__`. `__new__` is typically for (logically or physically) immutable objects.

Comment: I would use __init__ if I could assign directly to "self" rather than only attributes of self. So, is there a way to actually do this in __init__? How do I create a square array out of list objects and return just the square array? I am not looking to return is as something like, "self.yourArray" but just as "self" and I thought the class defined the object type.

Comment: I changed the 'return" to 
```
 return list.__new__(cls, template)
'''
and the "__str__" works now and the type reflects as "ArrayList" so thank you very much. It still says false on the "var1 is ArrayList" but "is" should have been "isinstance" and that works too! Much thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`collections.UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList). It is made for subclassing lists. This will allow you to assign to `self.data` in `__init__()` using your same code and avoid the issues with `__new__()`:

```
from collections import UserList
import copy

class ArrayList(UserList):
    def __init__(self, *dim, initial = []):
        self.data = None
        for d in range(len(dim)-1, -1, -1):
            if self.data is None:
                self.data = [initial for _ in range(dim[d])]
            else:
                self.data = [copy.deepcopy(self.data) for _ in range(dim[d])]

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(str(s) for s in self)

var1 = ArrayList(4,3,2,initial=0)
print(var1)
print(type(var1))   # <class 'list'>
print(isinstance(var1, ArrayList))
```

Prints:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
<class '__main__.ArrayList'>
True
```

Note that the docs suggest:

> Subclasses of UserList are expected to offer a constructor which can
> be called with either no arguments or one argument...
>
> ...If a derived class does not wish to comply with this requirement, all of the special methods supported by this class will need to be overridden

Which you're not doing here (although it may not matter for your purposes).

Also, it will probably be easier to just use Numpy if you haven't already considered that:

```
import numpy as np
np.zeros([4, 3, 2])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I looked first, but I am left wondering if "self.data" is a special attribute that is used how I was thinking of using "self" or is it just another attribute? I like this solution, and it may be more appropriate for a real-world project. Or is it something that only works for "UserList"? Anyway, thank you for this approach.

Comment: @JeffreyFlynt `self.data` is a documented attribute of the `UserList` class. `The instance’s contents are kept in a regular list, which is accessible via the data attribute of UserList instances.`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not using properly `__new__`: this magic method's job should be to handle the *creation* of a new instance of a certain class (that's why it should not return an object of another type), while `__init__` should handle its initialization.

The proper way to do this would be to completely ignore the `__new__` method (and I encourage you to continue doing so until you explicitly find yourself in a situation in which you cannot solve your problem with `__init__`), and instead use the latter.

In you're example, this would simply mean to move the code from `__new__` to `__init__`, and working on `self` instead of on a new object your create.

But you might have been confused on how to use them because there are few other errors which might have led to difficulties:

1. Let's start with simple stuff: within your comment block, you call `var1 is ArrayList`. The `is` operator does **not** check the type of an object. You should instead consider it as a stronger `==` operator (the difference being while the latter allows custom behavior by overloading, the former simply checks if both operands are the **same** object – same **id**).
2. It is unclear to me if it is useful for `ArrayList` to inherit from `list`: maybe that's what you would do in a more advanced/complex program, but really it doesn't bring you anything (even if what I am going to say is very anti-pythonic, but it's still true): most `list`-like types don't actually inherit from it, they simply internally store lists (or other more complex collections) and show an interface similar to `list`s. For instance, check the python doc for `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`, which are most likely what you will need.
3. Finally, and this is a more subtle error, you'll get out-of-nowhere errors because of a very stupid (IMO) python “feature”, which is: the `initial` variable within your constructor is consider *static* by python (even if static variables don't exist, the trick is that it is actually created only once, and you don't make a deep copy of it when creating, so whenever you will modify a single item, boom, every other item will take that value).

---

Just to be practical, I'll give you a few examples of how you could achieve what you want.

First, the “best” way (in the sense, the way you should use when becoming more experienced):

```py
import numpy
var1 = numpy.ndarray(4, 3, 2)
var1[1,0,1] = 5
# equivalent to
var1[1][0][1] = 5
# to initialize the whole array to some value
var1[:,:,:] = 0
```

The DIY way (only for educational purposes):

```py
class Array:
    def __init__(self, *dims, default=0):
        if len(dims) == 0:
            raise TypeError("Cannot have 0 dimentional arrays")
        elif len(dims) == 1:
            self._array = [default for i in range(dims[0])]
        else:
            self._array = [Array(*dims[1:], default=default) for i in range(dims[0])]
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._array[key]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._array[key] = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return '[' + ', '.join(repr(e) for e in self._array) + ']'
```

You could of course not want to create multiple arrays, but there are many ways to improve this. Just toy with it to understand it well.

**EDIT**:

Let's unshadow some points:

I/ **Static variables: ie 90% of the time, a very subtle bug that goes against the common sense, quite hard to debug**

Suppose I want to make a custom list class, but, for the sake of the simplicity, let's say I can only get items and append, and the actual list passed (optionally) when initialized:

```py
class MyList:
  def __init__(self, mylist=[]):
    self.mylist = mylist
  def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.mylist[key]
  def append(self, value):
    self.mylist.append(value)
```

Well, this code is **wrong**! Here is what might occur:

```py
a = MyList()
b = MyList()
a.append(3)
a[0] == 3 # true
b[0] == 3 # true?? wtf?
```

Actually, `a.mylist` is exactly the same object as `b.mylist`! I don't mean it's equal, I mean they really share the same memory section, changing one changes the other. This is because there is only one list that is ever created, and that is **when the MyList class was defined**, well before `a` was even created!

The correct code would be something like that:

```py
class MyList:
  def __init__(self, mylist=None):
    if mylist == None: self.mylist = []
    else: self.mylist = mylist
  # the rest of the code
```

II/ **Overloading the `__new__` magic method without actually creating the object**

It is very common for beginners to not understand the difference between `__new__` and `__init__`, and it is totally normal: this is because python does a lot behind the scenes, and for python there is a huge difference between those two, but for us, they are both called with the same arguments just before an object is created, so it's confusing. Let's dive in!

`__new__` really builds a new object from nothing, meaning you have to allocate the memory, and return the newly created object. You don't want to do that, unless you know what you are doing and have a very fine motive for doing so, right?

`__init__`, on the other hand, takes care of **initializing** the newly created object, which is why it is called right after `__new__`, and doesn't have to return anything: the new object is already created. This is where you want to add padding to your new list, or whatever you require. The other magic method has only the purpose of creating the object (meaning, getting the memory, saying python “Hey I exist”, etc.).

So, in the comment you wrote that the newly created object were None objects. This is very likely due to the fact that you overloaded `__new__`, but returned nothing. My advise is to simply forget about using `__new__` for the moment, most of what you will do won't require it.

Comment: I have used numpy a little but the lists are not necessarily purely numeric.The "initial" variable in the parameter in only used in __ new __ which is also "static." So, not only did I not think it mattered.
The second point you make is what good is there from inheriting from "list", and maybe not much, but I intended to add methods to "pad" out a list so that a list that has five elements could have an element[100] inserted at slot 100, and be padded with what I wanted. None of this has to be numbers, and I wanted all the rest of the list methods to work plus a few more to improve things..

Comment: Also, I could not get that code to work in the __ init __ method as I would have to assign the results to "self". When I did that, for reasons unknown t me, it return a NoneObject, IIRC. It seems you can assign to "self" but it is lost outside the class code. Now, another person suggested to use a special class which has a "self.data" and that works. It's so far kind of mysterious to me how, but I am cutting my teeth.

Comment: Well, if you only want to pad lists, you should instead create a class method direcrly for the list class

Comment: And, btw, for a method variable to be static is a completly different behaviour from a method itself being static: the point is, whenever you have static data within a function declaration, you're likely to have a bug. If you want, I can edit my post to provide you an example of weird behavior that may arise

Comment: Ok I'll edit my post to answer all your remarks because, after though, I may not have been clear enough!

Comment: The variable is actually a parameter. In the __ init __ section of almost every example I've seen they are often exactly the same as in the __ new __. For example:

class name(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

Here "name" is the same deal as my "initial". I think this is a non-issue. Initial is not part of the object.

I do not just intend to pad. The correct answer I needed was provided earlier. Unfortunately, I wish I could mark it as such, but the person replied rather than posting a separate post so I don't see how to mark it as the solution.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain more in details to you why it is wrong. But I understand it is hard to get the point behind what I say because it is really a corner case, it's just that when it happened to me I really wish someone told me before, because it was one of the most annoying bug I've seen.

Comment: oh and also I just noticed the ```for d in range(len(dims)-1, -1, -1)```. You could simply change that into ```for dimention in reversed(dims)```, and instead of accessing ```dims[d]```, directly use ```dimension```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219883/discussion-between-blackbeans-and-jeffrey-flynt).